# Extending the wired internal network to wireless by using PoE Access Points

Tags: router, wifi, access-point, mikrotik

Today we're running a Mikrotik 1100AHx2 at our office where we've four floors on different subnets.
Now I'm looking in to setting up a Wireless network spanning across these floors using Access Points, but all connected to the same router port so it's completely isolated from the rest of the networks, but still using the power from the switches from each floor.

So my question is, what kind of hardware would you use for this, and have someone made such a setup before?

This is quite hard to explain, so I drew you a picture to make it easier to understand, if you have any questions please just post them beneath, and if serverfault was the wrong place to post this, I'm sorry and please move it to wherever you want.

Best Regards
Lars
[image: Wifi setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You need to set up repeater/universal repeater mode on those APs.

Check TP Link WA 730 RE models...

http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WA730RE

Note: Do not expect miracles because it all depends from the signal between whose APs. Also, do not overload APs with to many users...

Comment: Would this create 1 single SSID+pw that devices would automatically be switched between, or 4 separate?

Comment: Yes. As you can see here http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/simulator/TL_WA830(UN)1.0/index.htm there is no SSID option when Range Extender mode is selected.

Comment: Ah, so if I have 1 of those in AP mode and the rest in Range Extender I get 1 single big wifi network then? and all devices connected will get IP addresses from the DHCP server in the Router, right?

Comment: Right. Just be sure that DHCP servers on every extender is disabled. The only DHCP server you'll need is router dhcp. Also, be sure that router IP address and IP addresses from the APs are not the same... Some extender will require "DHCP Relay" turned On (in case this option exists.)